# Bell that sits above trigger shifter?

Tags: safety, accessories

I'm looking for a bell that will sit above a trigger shifter on a flat bar bike.

Placement is a safety issue: in this location I can maintain hands on bars, brakes, shifters and warn pedestrians at the same time.

I've tried a bell that sits next to the shifter and I have to take my hand off the bar to reach it.

Attached are photos of the old bell that broke, showing the dimensions & placement that I'm looking for. Unfortunately I've been unable to find a replacement that fits. The bells that I've found don't have a ~1.5cm gap between the clamp and the body of the bell, and only have a couple of MM clearance.

[image: close-up of dismounted bell shown against a scale. The handlebar dimension of approximately 2.5cm is shown, as is approximately 1.5cm distance the bell sits above the bar.]

[image: Picture of the bell mounted directly behind the shifter on the bars]

[image: Another view of the bell mounted in relation to the shifter]

Comment: If you're happy with the old one, consider attempting a repair?  I see the striker is missing, perhaps 3D Printing a replacement is an option?

Comment: I think a piece of beer can or a small binder clip would repair it if all that’s missing is the striker. Just fold a piece of sheet metal over / clip the binder clip onto the little plastic stub that remains.

Comment: I've had one tall enough, but it was the stock bell on an old bike and recently broke

Comment: I wonder if new bells can be taken apart and a longer bolt and extra nut (or two or three) added under the working bell. (I do not own such a bell at the moment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On one of my bikes I've set things up so I can hold the bars, brake, and use the bell all at the same time. I did this by mounting the bell underneath the handlebar instead of on top, which gets a low one much closer to the grip.

Comment: I ended up fitting an airhorn instead of a piddly little bell, but that's more for getting heard by drivers of both car and truck.  I don't use it near pedestrians :)

Comment: @Criggie I keep wanting an electronic noise maker that imitates squealing brakes. That's the most effective sound when someone steps out without looking. For a while one urban beater bike had reliably noisy back brakes (now it needs a new back wheel, or at least hub)

Comment: Concur - horribly squeaky brakes are not a completely bad thing.  My shopper has a band brake that sounds like an old truck's drum brake .  Its horrible but the noise can be helpful.

Comment: We should convince manufacturers to make extra squealy brake pads/rotors!

Comment: @Erlkoenig on my disc-equipped tourer, with sintered pads, a waterpistol would be sufficient - they're quite noisy in the wet

Comment: Great idea. Perhaps the water pistol could be used to get some people's or drivers attention directly...

Comment: @Erlkoenig for cars I'd prefer a paintball marker gun, with the option of permanent paint as a warning to others in the worst cases

Comment: I sometimes dream of the kind of knives that were mounted on war chariots wheels (according to the comics I read.) But only coming out when needed.